# Getting error: "nvlink error : Undefined reference to '_ZN8Strategy8backtestEPddd'"

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, cuda, nvcc

I am getting the following error when running `make` for my CUDA (v7.5) application:

```
nvlink error : Undefined reference to '_ZN8Strategy8backtestEPddd'
```

I'm not sure why. It seems something is likely wrong with my Makefile. Here it is -- any ideas what might be causing the error? Thank you in advance!

```
CC = nvcc
CFLAGS = -std=c++11 -m64 -arch=compute_35 -code=sm_35 --compiler-options=-Wall,-Wno-unused-function,-Wno-unused-local-typedef,-Wno-unused-private-field
LFLAGS = -L/usr/local/lib -Llib $(shell pkg-config --libs libmongoc-1.0 libbson-1.0)
INCLUDES = -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -Iinclude $(shell pkg-config --cflags libmongoc-1.0 libbson-1.0)
LIBS = -lgsl -lcblas
BIN = ./bin
OBJDIR = ./obj
OBJ = factories/optimizationStrategyFactory.o positions/callPosition.o positions/putPosition.o \
      positions/position.o strategies/reversalsOptimizationStrategy.o strategies/optimizationStrategy.o \
      strategies/strategy.o factories/optimizerFactory.o optimizers/reversalsOptimizer.o optimizers/optimizer.o \
      factories/dataParserFactory.o dataParsers/oandaDataParser.o dataParsers/dataParser.o \
      studies/study.o studies/smaStudy.o studies/emaStudy.o studies/rsiStudy.o \
      studies/stochasticOscillatorStudy.o studies/polynomialRegressionChannelStudy.o

all: prepareData optimize

prepareData: src/prepareData.cu $(addprefix lib/,$(OBJ))
    @mkdir -p $(BIN)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -o $(BIN)/$@ src/prepareData.cu $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/,$(addprefix lib/,$(OBJ))) $(LFLAGS) $(LIBS)

optimize: src/optimize.cu $(addprefix lib/,$(OBJ))
    @mkdir -p $(BIN)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -o $(BIN)/$@ src/optimize.cu $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/,$(addprefix lib/,$(OBJ))) $(LFLAGS) $(LIBS)

%.o: %.cu
    @mkdir -p $(OBJDIR)/lib/strategies $(OBJDIR)/lib/positions $(OBJDIR)/lib/factories $(OBJDIR)/lib/optimizers $(OBJDIR)/lib/dataParsers $(OBJDIR)/lib/studies
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -o $(OBJDIR)/$@ --device-c $<
clean:
    rm -rf $(BIN) $(OBJDIR)
```

And here is the full compiler output:

```
rm -rf ./bin ./obj
nvcc -std=c++11 -m64 -arch=compute_35 -code=sm_35 --compiler-options=-Wall,-Wno-unused-function,-Wno-unused-local-typedef,-Wno-unused-private-field -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -Iinclude -I/usr/local/include/libmongoc-1.0 -I/usr/local/include/libbson-1.0 -o ./obj/lib/factories/optimizationStrategyFactory.o --device-c lib/factories/optimizationStrategyFactory.cu
nvcc -std=c++11 -m64 -arch=compute_35 -code=sm_35 --compiler-options=-Wall,-Wno-unused-function,-Wno-unused-local-typedef,-Wno-unused-private-field -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -Iinclude -I/usr/local/include/libmongoc-1.0 -I/usr/local/include/libbson-1.0 -o ./obj/lib/positions/callPosition.o --device-c lib/positions/callPosition.cu
nvcc -std=c++11 -m64 -arch=compute_35 -code=sm_35 --compiler-options=-Wall,-Wno-unused-function,-Wno-unused-local-typedef,-Wno-unused-private-field -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -Iinclude -I/usr/local/include/libmongoc-1.0 -I/usr/local/include/libbson-1.0 -o ./obj/lib/positions/putPosition.o --device-c lib/positions/putPosition.cu
nvcc -std=c++11 -m64 -arch=compute_35 -code=sm_35 --compiler-options=-Wall,-Wno-unused-function,-Wno-unused-local-typedef,-Wno-unused-private-field -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -Iinclude -I/usr/local/include/libmongoc-1.0 -I/usr/local/include/libbson-1.0 -o ./obj/lib/positions/position.o --device-c lib/positions/position.cu
nvcc -std=c++11 -m64 -arch=compute_35 -code=sm_35 --compiler-options=-Wall,-Wno-unused-function,-Wno-unused-local-typedef,-Wno-unused-private-field -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -Iinclude -I/usr/local/include/libmongoc-1.0 -I/usr/local/include/libbson-1.0 -o ./obj/lib/strategies/reversalsOptimizationStrategy.o --device-c lib/strategies/reversalsOptimizationStrategy.cu
nvcc -std=c++11 -m64 -arch=compute_35 -code=sm_35 --compiler-options=-Wall,-Wno-unused-function,-Wno-unused-local-typedef,-Wno-unused-private-field -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -Iinclude -I/usr/local/include/libmongoc-1.0 -I/usr/local/include/libbson-1.0 -o ./obj/lib/strategies/optimizationStrategy.o --device-c lib/strategies/optimizationStrategy.cu
nvcc -std=c++11 -m64 -arch=compute_35 -code=sm_35 --compiler-options=-Wall,-Wno-unused-function,-Wno-unused-local-typedef,-Wno-unused-private-field -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -Iinclude -I/usr/local/include/libmongoc-1.0 -I/usr/local/include/libbson-1.0 -o ./obj/lib/strategies/strategy.o --device-c lib/strategies/strategy.cu
nvcc -std=c++11 -m64 -arch=compute_35 -code=sm_35 --compiler-options=-Wall,-Wno-unused-function,-Wno-unused-local-typedef,-Wno-unused-private-field -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -Iinclude -I/usr/local/include/libmongoc-1.0 -I/usr/local/include/libbson-1.0 -o ./obj/lib/factories/optimizerFactory.o --device-c lib/factories/optimizerFactory.cu
nvcc -std=c++11 -m64 -arch=compute_35 -code=sm_35 --compiler-options=-Wall,-Wno-unused-function,-Wno-unused-local-typedef,-Wno-unused-private-field -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -Iinclude -I/usr/local/include/libmongoc-1.0 -I/usr/local/include/libbson-1.0 -o ./obj/lib/optimizers/reversalsOptimizer.o --device-c lib/optimizers/reversalsOptimizer.cu
nvcc -std=c++11 -m64 -arch=compute_35 -code=sm_35 --compiler-options=-Wall,-Wno-unused-function,-Wno-unused-local-typedef,-Wno-unused-private-field -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -Iinclude -I/usr/local/include/libmongoc-1.0 -I/usr/local/include/libbson-1.0 -o ./obj/lib/optimizers/optimizer.o --device-c lib/optimizers/optimizer.cu
nvcc -std=c++11 -m64 -arch=compute_35 -code=sm_35 --compiler-options=-Wall,-Wno-unused-function,-Wno-unused-local-typedef,-Wno-unused-private-field -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -Iinclude -I/usr/local/include/libmongoc-1.0 -I/usr/local/include/libbson-1.0 -o ./obj/lib/factories/dataParserFactory.o --device-c lib/factories/dataParserFactory.cu
nvcc -std=c++11 -m64 -arch=compute_35 -code=sm_35 --compiler-options=-Wall,-Wno-unused-function,-Wno-unused-local-typedef,-Wno-unused-private-field -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -Iinclude -I/usr/local/include/libmongoc-1.0 -I/usr/local/include/libbson-1.0 -o ./obj/lib/dataParsers/oandaDataParser.o --device-c lib/dataParsers/oandaDataParser.cu
nvcc -std=c++11 -m64 -arch=compute_35 -code=sm_35 --compiler-options=-Wall,-Wno-unused-function,-Wno-unused-local-typedef,-Wno-unused-private-field -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -Iinclude -I/usr/local/include/libmongoc-1.0 -I/usr/local/include/libbson-1.0 -o ./obj/lib/dataParsers/dataParser.o --device-c lib/dataParsers/dataParser.cu
nvcc -std=c++11 -m64 -arch=compute_35 -code=sm_35 --compiler-options=-Wall,-Wno-unused-function,-Wno-unused-local-typedef,-Wno-unused-private-field -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -Iinclude -I/usr/local/include/libmongoc-1.0 -I/usr/local/include/libbson-1.0 -o ./obj/lib/studies/study.o --device-c lib/studies/study.cu
nvcc -std=c++11 -m64 -arch=compute_35 -code=sm_35 --compiler-options=-Wall,-Wno-unused-function,-Wno-unused-local-typedef,-Wno-unused-private-field -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -Iinclude -I/usr/local/include/libmongoc-1.0 -I/usr/local/include/libbson-1.0 -o ./obj/lib/studies/smaStudy.o --device-c lib/studies/smaStudy.cu
nvcc -std=c++11 -m64 -arch=compute_35 -code=sm_35 --compiler-options=-Wall,-Wno-unused-function,-Wno-unused-local-typedef,-Wno-unused-private-field -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -Iinclude -I/usr/local/include/libmongoc-1.0 -I/usr/local/include/libbson-1.0 -o ./obj/lib/studies/emaStudy.o --device-c lib/studies/emaStudy.cu
nvcc -std=c++11 -m64 -arch=compute_35 -code=sm_35 --compiler-options=-Wall,-Wno-unused-function,-Wno-unused-local-typedef,-Wno-unused-private-field -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -Iinclude -I/usr/local/include/libmongoc-1.0 -I/usr/local/include/libbson-1.0 -o ./obj/lib/studies/rsiStudy.o --device-c lib/studies/rsiStudy.cu
nvcc -std=c++11 -m64 -arch=compute_35 -code=sm_35 --compiler-options=-Wall,-Wno-unused-function,-Wno-unused-local-typedef,-Wno-unused-private-field -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -Iinclude -I/usr/local/include/libmongoc-1.0 -I/usr/local/include/libbson-1.0 -o ./obj/lib/studies/stochasticOscillatorStudy.o --device-c lib/studies/stochasticOscillatorStudy.cu
nvcc -std=c++11 -m64 -arch=compute_35 -code=sm_35 --compiler-options=-Wall,-Wno-unused-function,-Wno-unused-local-typedef,-Wno-unused-private-field -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -Iinclude -I/usr/local/include/libmongoc-1.0 -I/usr/local/include/libbson-1.0 -o ./obj/lib/studies/polynomialRegressionChannelStudy.o --device-c lib/studies/polynomialRegressionChannelStudy.cu
nvcc -std=c++11 -m64 -arch=compute_35 -code=sm_35 --compiler-options=-Wall,-Wno-unused-function,-Wno-unused-local-typedef,-Wno-unused-private-field -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -Iinclude -I/usr/local/include/libmongoc-1.0 -I/usr/local/include/libbson-1.0 -o ./bin/prepareData src/prepareData.cu ./obj/lib/factories/optimizationStrategyFactory.o ./obj/lib/positions/callPosition.o ./obj/lib/positions/putPosition.o ./obj/lib/positions/position.o ./obj/lib/strategies/reversalsOptimizationStrategy.o ./obj/lib/strategies/optimizationStrategy.o ./obj/lib/strategies/strategy.o ./obj/lib/factories/optimizerFactory.o ./obj/lib/optimizers/reversalsOptimizer.o ./obj/lib/optimizers/optimizer.o ./obj/lib/factories/dataParserFactory.o ./obj/lib/dataParsers/oandaDataParser.o ./obj/lib/dataParsers/dataParser.o ./obj/lib/studies/study.o ./obj/lib/studies/smaStudy.o ./obj/lib/studies/emaStudy.o ./obj/lib/studies/rsiStudy.o ./obj/lib/studies/stochasticOscillatorStudy.o ./obj/lib/studies/polynomialRegressionChannelStudy.o -L/usr/local/lib -Llib -L/usr/local/lib -lsasl2 -lssl -lcrypto -lz -lmongoc-1.0 -lbson-1.0 -lgsl -lcblas
nvlink info    : Function '_ZN12CallPosition13getProfitLossEv' has address taken but no possible call to it
nvlink info    : Function '_ZN12CallPosition18getTransactionTypeEv' has address taken but no possible call to it
nvlink info    : Function '_ZN11PutPosition13getProfitLossEv' has address taken but no possible call to it
nvlink info    : Function '_ZN11PutPosition18getTransactionTypeEv' has address taken but no possible call to it
nvlink info    : Function '_ZN8PositionD1Ev' has address taken but no possible call to it
nvlink info    : Function '_ZN8PositionD0Ev' has address taken but no possible call to it
nvlink info    : Function '_ZN12CallPositionD1Ev' has address taken but no possible call to it
nvlink info    : Function '_ZN12CallPositionD0Ev' has address taken but no possible call to it
nvlink info    : Function '_ZN11PutPositionD1Ev' has address taken but no possible call to it
nvlink info    : Function '_ZN11PutPositionD0Ev' has address taken but no possible call to it
nvlink info    : Function '_ZN29ReversalsOptimizationStrategy8backtestEPddd' has address taken but no possible call to it
nvlink info    : Function '_ZN20OptimizationStrategy4tickEPd' has address taken but no possible call to it
nvlink info    : Function '_ZN8Strategy8backtestEPddd' has address taken but no possible call to it
nvlink error   : Undefined reference to '_ZN8Strategy8backtestEPddd' in './obj/lib/strategies/optimizationStrategy.o'
make: *** [prepareData] Error 255
```

Note this started happening around the time I added `--device-c` (which some code changes require).

Comment: `_ZN8Strategy8backtestEPddd`demangles to `Strategy::backtest(double*, double, double)`. Only you know where that function is (or should be) defined and compiled and linked to your code.

Comment: It's declared in the [base header](https://github.com/chaddjohnson/forex-backtesting/blob/cuda/include/strategies/strategy.cuh#L32) and the [child header](https://github.com/chaddjohnson/forex-backtesting/blob/cuda/include/strategies/reversalsOptimizationStrategy.cuh#L21) file and defined in the [child implementation](https://github.com/chaddjohnson/forex-backtesting/blob/cuda/lib/strategies/reversalsOptimizationStrategy.cu#L17) file, but maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: I think you need to read up a bit on the device linker and the separate compilation module. I don't see any explicit device linker phase in your makefile, and I guess you need one.

Comment: Found the problem (in my answer)! Thank you for your help -- it set me in the right direction.

Comment: Please make sure you remember come back and accept your answer after the waiting period has expired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out objects passed to CUDA kernels cannot have virtual functions. See [this](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/825046/can-cuda-properly-handle-pure-virtual-classes-/?offset=4) thread.

However, it seems that objects instantiated and used only within the kernel can have virtual functions.